# How to convert the start date and end date of an event object in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

When I click the event in FullCalendar and I took the start and end property of the event, it is displaying this result:

[image: Result]

Note: I used the eventClick function based on the FullCalendar Documentation. This is my code.

```
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {         

            alert ('Event ID: ' + calEvent.id + ' Event Title: ' + calEvent.title + ' Event Start: ' + calEvent.start + ' Event End: ' + calEvent.end);
            alert ('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
            alert ('View: ' + view.name );

            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        },
```

Is there a way to convert the start date to a real date? Like 2017-11-13? Since I set the start date to "2017-11-13", I want the output of calEvent.start to be the same. Thanks.

Here is the code where I set the date.

```
    Calendar c = new Calendar();
    c.setId(1);
    c.setStart("2017-11-13");
    c.setEnd("2017-11-14");
    c.setTitle("Event#1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```js
var d = new Date(1510531200000);
var str = d.getUTCFullYear() + "\-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "\-" + d.getDate();
alert(str);
```

Repalce the number `1510531200000` with your variable name.

Comment: This works, of course, but just to comment that momentJS's "format" function can do this much more nicely without using string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(var d = new Date(1346025600000000);
var str = d.getUTCFullYear() + "\-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "\-" + d.getDate();
alert(str););
var str = d.getUTCFullYear() + "\-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "\-" + d.getDate();
alert(str);
```